# Calculate sum of N preceding values

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am write a SQL query to replicate below Excel result.

In Column A I have 252 values in ASC order from 10/30/2018 to 10/29/2019
In Column BV I have respective PL Number
I want to calculate TestPL column having value as Ignore first 3 PL Values and 4th Cell would be addition of B2:B5, 5th Cell would be B3:B6 and so on for all 251 values

TestPL should start from row 4 and should have sum of cells B2:B5, and row 5 would be  B3:B6 and so on in a stream till row 252 which would B249:B252

[image]

Comment: Please see how to write a [minimal, complete, verifiable question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) so we can best help you.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what more I have to add

Comment: I don’t understand what your question is? You’ve put the excel formulas in the sheet. Just put a = in front `=SUM( whatever )`

Comment: You could put some actual SQL code, like the link describes, instead of asking people to manually convert your image into a test schema, sample data, and sample output. And any actual SQL logic you have so far would help, too. Maybe [this post](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) will be more clear as to how to help us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
...sum(PL) over(order by [Date] range between 3 preceding and current row)
```

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio Works perfectly for my requirement.